# Breeze BeforeSaveEntity is not being called

Tags: breeze

I can't figure out why BeforeSaveEntity() is not being called when I save my new comments.  The comments are saved to the database but the fields that I modify on the server are not being updated.  Break points in the BeforeSaveEntity function are not hit.  SaveChanges() is run.

```
//server controller
public class LeaseRepository : EFContextProvider<LeaseEntities>
{

    public LeaseRepository(IPrincipal user)
    {
        //                
    }

    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
        var entity = entityInfo.Entity;

        if (entity is LeaseComment)
        {
            return BeforeSaveComment(entity as LeaseComment, entityInfo);
        }
        return base.BeforeSaveEntity(entityInfo);
    }

    private bool BeforeSaveComment(LeaseComment c, EntityInfo info)
    {
       // c.Comment = "server comment!";

        if (info.EntityState == EntityState.Added)
        {
            c.UserId = AgentId;// AdName;
            c.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
        }

        return true;
    }


    private readonly EFContextProvider<LeaseEntities>
        _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<LeaseEntities>();

    private LeaseEntities Context { get { return _contextProvider.Context; } }

    public string Metadata
    {
        get { return _contextProvider.Metadata(); }
    }

    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Deleting these two functions fixed it.

```
public string Metadata
{
    get { return _contextProvider.Metadata(); }
}

public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
    return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}
```

I'm guessing the SaveChanges() was the problem.